# Flask OAuth Github POST requests

Tags: python, oauth, flask, github-api

I'm working with Flask on [bakery](https://github.com/xen/bakery) project (idea is similar to Travis CI, but done in python). And making module that add webhooks for repositories that own authorized github user. I don't paste here full example code, here is snippet of what I'm trying to do. Full example available in [separate gist](https://gist.github.com/xen/5369706).

Problem is that Github API GET requests are working without any problems. But the same time POST return status `401` and `{"message":"Bad credentials"}` in responce body.

```py
# this method is working
@app.route('/repos')
def repos():
    # only logged in user should call it, but I skip it in this example
    resp = github.get('/user/repos', data = {'type': 'public'})
    # responce status code is ok, and data is returned
    print(resp.data) # should print to console

@app.route('/addhook/<path:full_name>')
def repos(full_name):
    HOOK_URL = 'http://example.com/hook'
    resp = github.post('/repos/%(full_name)s/hooks' % {'full_name': full_name},
        data = {
            'name':'web',
            'active': True,
            'events': ['push'],
            'config': {
                'url': HOOK_URL,
                'content_type': 'json'
            }
         },
         format = 'json'
    )
    # POST request is not working and form request that Github is not understand
    print(resp.status, resp.data)
```

I checked what headers generate Flask-OAuth and found that it add additional header line with this contents (skip real values):

```
authorization: 'OAuth realm="https://api.github.com", oauth_body_hash="...", oauth_nonce="...", oauth_timestamp="...", oauth_consumer_key="...", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_token="XXX", oauth_signature="..."
```

And as result Github returns this status and probably don't understand what to do with this. I found workaround, if I only copy token and call Github API directly then I can getting expected result. Here is equivalent curl call:

```sh
$ curl https://api.github.com/repos/xen/league-gothic/hooks?access_token=XXX -X POST --data '{"name":"web","active":true,"events": ["push"],"config": {"url": "http://example.com/hook","content_type": "json"}}'
```

So, question is: is it possible to make it looks better and use Flask OAuth method POST to simplify code and make it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding problem I described in my question. Here is monkey patch that solves it:

```py
# monkey patch OAuth
import oauth2
old_request = oauth2.Request
del oauth2.Request
class NewRequest(old_request):
    def to_header(self, realm=''):
        """According Github documentation this is enough for authentication
        http://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication."""
        return {'Authorization': 'token %s' % self['oauth_token']}

oauth2.Request = NewRequest
# end monkey patch
```

This is ad hoc solution and probably is not very helpfull for other people who will have the similar problems with Flask-OAuth and dependency modules. OAuth2 looks outdated does not support PATCH method and may be have other problems, likely you can follow advice from Max Countryman and give a try to `rauth`. Module have [Flask example](https://github.com/litl/rauth/tree/master/examples/facebook). <del>Also exists port of Flask-OAuth with rauth support called [Flask-Rauth](http://flask-rauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)</del> Doesn't work since rauth API update.

Answer (score 4):

I believe Flask-Oauth uses python-oauth2, which is pretty outdated at this point. You might consider using a different client library. I can recommend [rauth](https://github.com/litl/rauth). In particular, check out the Facebook Flask example. Full disclosure I am the author of rauth.

Comment: Max, actually digging after I made a monkey patch to to_header method in Request class in OAuth2. But I found other problems after and not sure that it is finite chain of problems and fixes. Probably I'll try to switch to your lib. For example it have HTTP PATCH method support. Thank you very much for your link, examples and this answer.

Comment: @MikhailKashkin glad to hear you were able to fix it! If you do decide to try rauth, feel free to ping me with any questions you may have.

Answer (score 2):

Flask-OAuth is outdated as @maxcountryman said.

There is another replacement for Flask-OAuth: [Flask-OAuthlib](https://flask-oauthlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

It has an example of GitHub: https://github.com/lepture/flask-oauthlib/blob/master/example/github.py

Comment: I considered to use rauth and posted example on wiki how to use it with GitHub https://github.com/litl/rauth/wiki/Use-cases